# Eclipse freezes when adding components to window design

Tags: java, eclipse, freeze

I am encountering a problem in eclipse window builder and it's whenever I try to add new components to the window in the window design mode the eclipse suddenly freezes for 2 minutes. The scroller bar on the right starts jumping up and down and I can't press anything.

This happens only when I move my mouse to the window of application area, after I have selected which component to add. If I just stay on the selection of components area it doesn't occur only when I move my mouse to try and add the chosen component.

Please help I don't know what to do.

**pic 1:**
[image]

**pic 2:**
[image]

Comment: Looks like what you actually need to do is report a bug to the Eclipse developers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a bug report appears to be more appropriate and it's not exactly a *programming* problem.

Comment: If you post an [MCVE] reproducing the problem others can try it as well